# How to convert the following stored procedure to a prepared statement?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement, sql-function

The following stored procedure only accepts parameters where a real integer is explicitly written out. E.g.: `CALL test11(46)`.

I’d like it re-written so it can accept something similar to the following:

```
SELECT *, CALL test11(vendor_id) FROM vendors;
```

Or

```
CALL test11(SELECT vendor_id FROM vendors WHERE vendor_name = 'Micro Center');
```

I understand the first/former is pointless, since an IF statement can be implemented without having to resort to a stored procedure. But I find the latter very crucial to know.

Stored procedure syntax:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE test11(IN vendor_id_var INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE sum_balance_due_var DECIMAL(9, 2);

    SELECT SUM(invoice_total - payment_total - credit_total)
    INTO sum_balance_due_var 
    FROM invoices i
    JOIN vendors v ON v.vendor_id = i.vendor_id
    WHERE i.vendor_id = vendor_id_var
    GROUP BY i.vendor_id, vendor_name;

    IF sum_balance_due_var > 0 THEN
        SELECT CONCAT('Balance due: $', sum_balance_due_var) AS message;
    ELSE
        SELECT 'Balance paid in full' AS message;
    END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

---

Vendors table:

```
CREATE TABLE vendors (
    vendor_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    vendor_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   -- other columns
)
```

Invoices table:

```
CREATE TABLE invoices (
    invoice_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    vendor_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    invoice_total DECIMAL(9,2) NOT NULL,
    payment_total DECIMAL(9,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    credit_total DECIMAL(9,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    -- other columns
)
```

Some sample data:

```
INSERT INTO vendors (vendor_id, vendor_name) VALUES (34, 'IBM');
INSERT INTO vendors (vendor_id, vendor_name) VALUES (37, 'Blue Cross');
INSERT INTO invoices (invoice_id, vendor_id, invoice_total, payment_total, credit_total) VALUES (19, 34, 116.54, 116.54, 0.00);
INSERT INTO invoices (invoice_id, vendor_id, invoice_total, payment_total, credit_total) VALUES (52, 34,1083.58,1083.58, 0.00);
INSERT INTO invoices (invoice_id, vendor_id, invoice_total, payment_total, credit_total) VALUES (46, 37, 224.00, 224.00, 0.00);
INSERT INTO invoices (invoice_id, vendor_id, invoice_total, payment_total, credit_total) VALUES (50, 37, 116.00, 116.00, 0.00);
INSERT INTO invoices (invoice_id, vendor_id, invoice_total, payment_total, credit_total) VALUES (113, 37,224.00,   0.00, 0.00);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define it as a `FUNCTION`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION test11(IN vendor_id_var INT)
RETURNS text -- or whatever type you want returned
BEGIN
    -- your existing code

    RETURN <something>
END
```

and remove the word `CALL`:

```
SELECT *, test11(vendor_id)
FROM vendors
```

It's a UDF, just use as if it were a built in.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response.

Comment: In regards to RETURN <something>: In each IF STATEMENT I did, ... AS message INTO str_message;
Then: RETURN str_message; which was declared as VARCHAR(200). 
If there's a better a way to do that it would be appreciated. Returning a column a alias wasn't permitted.

Comment: I found the better solution. I went ahead and an put RETURN within each of IF-statements and got rid of the column alias.